# How to make a clean clang front-end?

Tags: c++, llvm, clang, frontend, backend

I'm working on a C++ source analyzer project and it seems that clang is nice candidate for
the parsing work. The problem is that clang heavily depends on the infrastructure "llvm" project,
How do I configure it to get a clean front-end without any concrete machine oriented backend?
Just like LCC does, they provide a "null" backend for people who focus on parser parts.
Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Apart from a few Support library (which provides some utility classes and OS-independant code) you should not need the full LLVM. Which libraries of Clang are you using ?

Comment: I'm going to use whole clang executable but with a dummy back-end.

Comment: Do you know about `libclang` ? It's a C library (with a guaranteed stable interface) that can expose the Clang AST. It's much more lightweight. Otherwise, you may simply use the C++ libraries (beware that the interface is *not* stable), the executable embeds stuff that won't be really useful for you, I think.

Comment: maybe you're right Matthieu. my approach is get a workable thing,plant some my code for the application, then reduce the code base step by step. the drawback is that dependencies are too much.

Comment: If you'd like to checkout `libclang`, you might like to checkut [this presentation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587140/any-tutorial-on-how-to-use-clang-for-syntax-highlighting-and-code-completion/7250322#7250322)

Comment: did you figure out a way?? if yes how did you do this please tell as i'm in a similar situation now...

Comment: Probably off-topic, probably helpful:
Have a look at the sources of the [SublimeClang](https://github.com/quarnster/SublimeClang) plugin for the text editor [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/2). Works really really well for me.

Comment: To Aditya: have a look at the link: http://devimages.apple.com/llvm/videos/Libclang.mov

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I recently did this on Windows.

Download the clang and llvm source from [here](http://llvm.org/releases/download.html).

Install cmake and Python (contrary to the docs, you do need Python just to build clang; at least, cmake gives up if it can't find a Python runtime).

You also need VS2008 or VS2010.

One thing that's not entirely obvious is the required directory structure:

```
projectRoot
    build  <- intermediate build files and DLLs, etc. will go here
    llvm  <- contents of llvm-3.0.src from llvm-3.0.tar go here
        tools
            clang  <- contents of clang-3.0.src from clang-3.0.tar go here
```

And follow the [windows build instructions](http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html) from step 4 onwards.  Don't attempt to use the cmake GUI, it's a horror; just use the commands given in the build instructions.

Once the build is complete (which takes a while) you'll have:

```
projectRoot
    build
        bin
            Release  <- libclang.dll will be here
        lib
            Release  <- libclang.lib will be here
    llvm
        tools
            clang
                include
                    clang-c  <- Index.h is here
```

Index.h defines the API to access information about your source code; it contains quite a bit of documentation about the APIs.

To get started using clang you need something like:

```
CXIndex index = clang_createIndex(1, 1);

// Support Microsoft extensions
char *args[] = {"-fms-extensions"};

CXTranslationUnit tu = clang_parseTranslationUnit(index, "mySource.c", args, ARRAY_SIZE(args), 0, 0, 0);

if (tu)
{
    CXCursor cursor = clang_getTranslationUnitCursor(tu);

    // Use the cursor functions to navigate through the AST
}
```

Comment: Thanks arx! I'm trying your approach.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you cannot get "pure" front-end without machine-specific details. C/C++ are inherently machine-tied languages. Think about preprocessor and built-in defines, the sizes of the builtin types, etc. Some of these can be abstracted out, but not e.g. preprocessor.